# Can we use existing google calendar api in multiple domain?

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

Hope you are doing well..!!

I have a question , I have an existing website where already integrated google calendar api . Now I have another new website so my question here is , may I use existing website google calendar api in this new domain or not ?

or need to buy for new domain again ?

Thanks,
Anks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website that users Google calendar api.  So you have created a project on Google cloud console. either with service account credentials or web credentials.  That is considered to be a single application.

When you go and create a new website and which to also use an api you should create a new project on Google cloud console for this application.  The main reason for this would be quota. If you use the same project on google cloud console then both websites would be sharing the quota.

I cant tell you if you need to buy a new domain name for your website i guess that would depend upon your needs.   If by domain you mean google workspace domain.   Assuming you are using service accounts to store the web app calendar data, i dont see any reason it couldn't be under the same workspace domain.   Just make sure you create separate projects in google cloud console to avoid the quota issue i mentioned.